# Useless Store and load

Tags: assembly, arm

In a decompile program I cam accross the following instruction:

```
890c:       e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
8910:       e50b100c        str     r1, [fp, #-12]
8914:       e51b0008        ldr     r0, [fp, #-8]
8918:       e51b100c        ldr     r1, [fp, #-12]
```

What is the point of the last 2 ldr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers emit those when not at full optimization. Lines like

```
a = 0;
return a;
```

when compiled for debugging, would look somewhat like that.

Re:comment: in that case, it's most likely a call sequence

```
a = something; //compiler: calculate in register, write out to memory
b = something_else; //compiler: calculate in register, write out to memory
Func(a, b); //compiler: pick up from memory, branch and link to the function
```

Comment: The next instruction is a `bl` that explain it all.

Answer (score 0):

The other possibility is that the program is modifying memory mapped I/O registers.

Comment: IO Mapped at [fp, #-8] ?

Comment: There's no reason `fp` couldn't be used as a general purpose register